# Download file in all browser which store on (google cloud storage) with url in js

Tags: google-cloud-storage

After uploading a file to a GCS bucket, that is publically readbale, when I access the file directly (https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/test/documents/business/4lS49Z1gVJ-km@9be-LOADMAXChatbot.png) the browser (Chrome) downloads the file, instead of displaying it.

Comment: What does this have to do with Go or programming?

Comment: Most likely you didn't set the correct [Content-Type](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#content-type).